# Can you use different bundles for the AlarmManager setInexactRepeating?

Tags: android

I want to set up a repeating alarm which sends on its first trigger with Bundles the string "test".

Is it possible on the next trigger to have another string like "test2" ?

Alarm manager:

```
    // Enable the scheduled alarm to send notifications
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, Service.class);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("test", "test");
    alarmIntent.putExtras(extras);

    PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Set the alarm in 30 minutes and repeat it every 30 minutes.
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            1000,
            alarmPendingIntent);
```

IntentService:

```
public class Service extends IntentService {

public Service() {
    super("service");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String test = intent.getStringExtra("test");
    // update the bundle data
    Log.i("result", test);

    // how to update here the string to "test2" ?
}
}
```

I want on the second trigger the value of `String test` to be `test2`.

But I always get the original value from the first trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need separate alarms and separate `PendingIntent`s. You can either set them up at the same time, or set an alarm that does not repeat and have the service set the following alarm whenever it runs.

Note that if you set the two alarms at the same time, you need something other than the extras to be different because Android does not compare intent extras when it checks for an existing `PendingIntent` for the given `Intent`. One way to do this is like so:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
...
alarmIntent.putExtras(extras);
alarmIntent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
```